# $.post() data to Codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, api

I have an `$.post()` and i want receive the data into my controller, how could i do that?

## jQuery

```
$.post($('#url').val() + "Dashboard/getApi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv this is my url vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
$('#url').val() + "Dashboard/getApi" = "http://127.0.0.1/M2MWare/Dashboard/getApi"
```

## And this is my controller

```
function getApi()
    {
    $valores = $this->input->post();
    // print_r($valores);
    return json_encode($valores);
    }
```

this returns me an empty array, i tried with different url, data and nothing why?

Comment: `echo json_encode($valores);` not `return json_encode($valores);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Nothing, returns _[]_

Comment: You are passing a wrong Url, from where are you getting this `$('#url').val()`

Comment: How about just `echo json_encode($_POST);` - does that produce anything different?

Comment: @Franco so, how its the proper way write the url of my controller? the file rute its: _application/controllers/Dashboard.php_ and inside the controller i have the function _getApi()_, as i read in the codeigniter 3 docs, the route it's _http://127.0.0.1/folder/controller/function_ im wrong?

Comment: @Will i think it's the url that isnt working, because `echo json_encode($_POST);` doesnt work

Comment: OK - you can try navigating to the URL directly in a browser, to see if you are hitting the correct action?

Comment: This has nothing to do with echoing the response @RocketHazmat already pointed to this

Comment: @Gil My question is still not answered, From where are you getting this `$('#url').val()`. It is no use to go on if this is not clear

Comment: @Franco `$('#url').val()` = `<input type="hidden" id="url" value="<?=base_url()?>">` and `<?=base_url()?>`  = `http://127.0.0.1/M2MWare/`

**edit:** that input hidden comes from my base layout

Comment: You can not address the `base_url()` like this because is not a variable. 
You need to reference it like this:
<input type="hidden" id="url" value="<?php  echo base_url(); ?>">

Comment: Additionally you don't need to pass the full `url` to the `$.post` the call to your controller/method will be enough. `Codeigniter` has a csrf protection and probably you will need to pass a token (This depends on your configuration settings). You need to use the framework conventions from the beginning otherwise it will be very difficult to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 3.1.0 running on WampServer.

**The Dashboard Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('post_view');
    }

    function getApi() {
        $valores = $this->input->post();
        echo json_encode($valores);
    }
}
```

**The View post_view.php** This is Very Bare Bones for simplicity.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Post Me</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="url" value="http://ci310tut.com/">
</form>

<script src="<?= base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('We should be seeing an alert popup');
        $.post($('#url').val() + "Dashboard/getApi", {name: "John", time: "2pm"})
            .done(function (data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And from the above I get an alert screaming at me each time I perform a page refresh with the provided data being displayed.

So you might want to check the above against what you have.